# PHP - Trim is not working when word comes through GET request

Tags: php, trim

[PHP] - Trim is not working when word comes through GET request

My Script as Below:

```
if(isset($_GET['use'])){
    $usage = $_GET['use'];
    $str = "Hello World";
    echo $str . "<br>";
    echo rtrim($str,$usage);
}
```

> #### and result should be:
>
> when url end with       =       index.php?use=World
>   echo $str = Hello World
>   echo rtrim($str,$usage) == Hello

but this not work for me, why ?

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Comment: Hello World
Hello World

Comment: First problem is that you seem to be under the misconception that rtrim() will remove a specific __sequence__ of characters from the right of the string..... it won't, it will remove any occurrence of the specifi characters in any order, because it's simply an unordered list of characters to be removed, not a sequence

Comment: `rtrim()` is case sensitive. Make sure value of _use_ is exactly what you need.

Comment: Please write down the example here or set demo here because i am unable to understand what you want to say. In my case i already has try left right but no got positive result

Answer (score 0):

When I run your example code it outputs

> Hello

It seems you've done something wrong.

When I tried with

> index.php?use=Worlds

It still outputs

> Hello

When I tried

> index.php?use=Worl

It outputs

> Hello World

Comment: Oh my God !, Really ? but i try from last one hour not possible dear brother please give me the Code which you tried

Comment: I'm using php 5.5.15 in xampp 1.8.3 on windows 7 machine.

Comment: I thing you are using use variable in your page somewhere which is overwriting hence try with some other variable like use12